# Getting last modification date of files in directory using PHP

Tags: php, date

I am trying to get the last modification date of all files in a directory using PHP.

I am using this:

```
foreach($dir as $file) 
{
$mod_date=date("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($file));
}
```

`foreach($dir as $file)` is returning the correct files, but all of the modification dates are coming back as 0000-00-00 00:00:00, instead of the actual modification date.

What changes do I need to make to get this working?

Comment: Is the function returning an error or false?

Comment: How are you opening `$dir` and is its path different than that of where the script is running?  You probably need to prepend the path to the directory to `$file` before calling `filemtime`.

Comment: @drew010 I am setting the directory as follows: `$dir = glob("/home/******/public_html/monthlymixup.com/mixups/april_2011/media/*/*");`  And the path of the script is `/home/******/public_html/monthlymixup.com/process.php'`  How would I prepend the directory?

Comment: `$file` returns the full path of the file correctly.

Comment: @Nick Since you are using glob, it has the path on the file, no need.  If you used `opendir` then it only returns the file name.

Comment: I can now see that the date is actually being returned, but not in the format that I need it to be in for submitting to a MySQL database, which was where I was reading the `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.  I should have included this info!  Now I need to work out how to convert convert `February 23 2012 11:26:32` to `2012-02-23 11:26:32` so that I can submit it to database

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check if the $file var is actually pointing to a correct file

```
foreach($dir as $file) 
{
  if(is_file($file))
  {
    $mod_date=date("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($file));
    echo "<br>$file last modified on ". $mod_date;
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<br>$file is not a correct file";
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, I am getting, e.g. `/home/******/public_html/monthlymixup.com/mixups/april_2011/media/nick/_say boss man.mp3 last modified on February 23 2012 11:26:32.
`  I can now see that the issue is that the date is in the wrong format for submitting to a MySQL table, which was where I was reading the 0000-00-00 00:00:00.  I should have included this info!  Do you know how I convert `February 23 2012 11:26:32` to `2012-02-23 11:26:32`?

Comment: Try this: `echo date("Y-m-d G:i:s",strtotime("February 23 2012 11:26:32"));`

For your code I guess it will become `date("Y-m-d G:i:s",strtotime($mod_date));`

Alternately, while getting the filemtime() itself you could do `date("Y-m-d G:i:s",filemtime($file));`

Comment: @Nick, Better use `DateTime` object and `createFromFormat()` method instead of `strtotime()`.

Answer (score 4):

`date("F d Y H:i:s.", false)` is what you are getting. see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) of `filemtime`. It returns false on failure.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use `glob` function, why not use `scandir` function. 
Secondly, you could easily get the date format you want by using `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", filemtime($file))`