# Have a PHP script detect if a new file has been uploaded and log information about that file to MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing something rather complex here (for me at least), and I'm not sure where to look in terms of resources. I don't need anyone to write this for me, maybe just a link where I can find a tutorial?

I have a folder on my website that holds all the articles on that site. I also have a MySql database that holds a table of contents for the articles. Right now I have to manually edit the MySql database every time I upload a new directory. I was wondering if I am able to automate this with PHP.

Each of the articles is a separate subdirectory with an index.html file inside of it, along with any subpages and images. How do I detect when a new article has been uploaded to the main folder, find out the location of said article, as well as read an XML (or JSON? I'm not sure yet, which do you suggest?) file inside the article directory that defines the Name of the article, the data it was created, and other information and log all that to the Mysql Database?

This code must not log an article twice, as the information within the database will be picked up by another script that will display a list of all my articles.

i am wondering if the idea I have is even do-able, or does it need to be thrown away? If it is possible, are there any resources that offer tutorials on things related to this?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853935/getting-last-modification-date-of-files-in-directory-using-php

Comment: Why not just gather the information you need and log it right after you upload the files?

Comment: @Literphor I suppose I could do that, But the reason I started my website was so that I can learn to code. This sounded like an interesting thing I could try. Also because I tend to forget to do this kind of stuff *a lot*.

Comment: @Richie378 - You can come up with 100 million ways to do what you want but the best programmers care only about the simplest solutions.